# How to retain RasterStack layer names when using ClusterR reclassify?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, stack, r-raster

When I try to reclassify a RasterStack using ClusterR, the output contains names Layer.1, Layer.2, Layer.3 instead of the original stack layer names salinity, temp, depth.  Here is the command that I am using:

```
stackr <- clusterR(stack, reclassify, args=list(rcl=cbind(NA, 0)))
```

How can I retain the original names in the output stack?

Edit:  I just figured out that you can reassign the names from the original stack like this:

```
names(stackr) = names(stack)
```

However, is it guaranteed that the layers in the output stack are in the same order as the original after parallel-processing?

Comment: Yes, the layers are always in the same order as in the input data. It would a terrible mess if they were not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It's simply a matter of reassigning the names from the original stack.

```
names(stackr) = names(stack)
```